# Reg: Session Management

Tags: java, session

Hi I need a clarification regarding session management. I want to keep away the session from the server's jvm that is I don't want the session to be stored in the web server. Also I want the session to be stateless. And I want the cross domain single sign on to be implemented. Can someone give me a better approach or tool for achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Baadshah You missed the subject and the verb, and there are 7 question marks too many... :)

Answer (score 0):

A stateless session? Think about pesisting it in database then.